# Store value in SharedPreference and get From it in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am new to android and i have been using this code to save the value of my Checkboxes
when the app closes which works fine (in Settings.class)

```
        public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =     this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
        editor.commit();        
        }
        public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return isChecked;       

        }
```

but i want to use the same saved value in another activity  (Progress.class)

here are my activities

**Settings.class**

```
          checkBox_one = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

          boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
          Log.i("start",""+isChecked);
          checkBox_one.setChecked(isChecked);
          //checkBox_one.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
          checkBox_one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("boolean",""+isChecked);
                Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");
            }
          });

          checkBox_two = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

          boolean isCheckedTwo = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedTwo");
          checkBox_two.setChecked(isCheckedTwo );
          //checkBox_two.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
          checkBox_two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

                Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedTwo");
            }
          });

          checkBox_three = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

          boolean isCheckedThree = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedThree");
          checkBox_three.setChecked(isCheckedThree );
          checkBox_three.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

                Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedThree");
            }
          });

          checkBox_four = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

          boolean isCheckedFour = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedFour");
          checkBox_four.setChecked(isCheckedFour );
          //checkBox_four.setChecked(true);//Enable By Default
          checkBox_four.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

                Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedFour");
            }
          });

          checkBox_five = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);

          boolean isCheckedFive = getBooleanFromPreferences("isCheckedFive");
          checkBox_five.setChecked(isCheckedFive );
          checkBox_five.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {

                Settings.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isCheckedFive");
            }
          });

        }

        public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
        editor.commit();        
        }
        public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return isChecked;       

        }
        //-------------------------//
```

and here is **Progress.Class**

```
        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                updateProgressBars();
            }
        });

        checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                updateProgressBars();
            }
        });
        }

        public void updateProgressBars() {

          progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

         if (checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
            progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         } else if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
```

Comment: instantiate your sharepreferences object in below manner in your get and set methods SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently implemented same requirement in my application. I followed below process.

Since you already created the sharedpreferences, Now in target activity use as below.

```
SharedPreferences setprefsd=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

now get boolean as show below:

```
setprefsd.getBoolean(Key,Value)   //key is the one which you have used while declaring
```

Let me know how it goes

Edit--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Change key like this as key should be a `String` value and make `isChecked` static to access from another activity

To put the value in shared preferences

```
  editor.getBoolean("key", isChecked);
```

To retrive the value

setprefsd.getBoolean("Key", isChecked)

Edit2------------------------------------------------------
change your share preferences insertion as below.

```
public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("key", isChecked);
        editor.commit();       


    }
```

Comment: hello there. do you know a tutorial for showing available ram and internal memory on a textview?

Comment: hello siva i have lost the code for enabling/disabling airplane mode,but i have sent you that code in the chat room, can you pls give me that cod?

Comment: Hello nikka...sorry for late reply need to check will let you know tomorrow

Comment: hey thanks for the help, i have searched for it on google (our chat). and i found it

Comment: do you know how to hide images/video from a gridview by a .nomedia file?